# JDBC can't find the correct MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When I run this code to connect to the database and add an object

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {
public static void main(String [] args) {
    try {
        //Get connection to DB
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://LocalHost:3306/interndata?useSSL=false" , "root" , "Starwars991211");
        //Create a statement 
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int entryNum, citNum ;
        String date, score ;
        String keepGoing = "y";

        while (keepGoing.equals("y") || keepGoing.equals("Y")){
            System.out.println("Enter the id");
            entryNum = scan.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println("Enter the date");
            date = scan.next(); 
            System.out.println("Enter the citnum");
            citNum = scan.nextInt(); 
            System.out.println("Enter the score");
            score = scan.next(); 
            String sql = "INSERT INTO employee (EntryNumber, Date, ``CriterionNum, Score)"   + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = myConn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, entryNum);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, date);
            preparedStatement.setInt(3,citNum);
            preparedStatement.setString(4, score);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); 
            System.out.print("Another factorial? (y/n) ");
            keepGoing = scan.next();
        }           
        //Execute SQL query
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from teacherexample");
        //process result set
        while (myRs.next()) {
            System.out.println("ID: " + myRs.getInt("EntryNumber") + " Name: " + myRs.getString("Date") + ", " + myRs.getInt("CriterionNum") + "  " +  myRs.getString("Score"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I get this error

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'interndata.employee' doesn't exist

`internexample.employee` is what `interndata.teacherexample` used to be called before I changed it's name.

My question is why is the program still trying to connect to the older database that does not exist even thought there is no mention of it in the code?

Comment: do you have access to this table ? and why do you have `` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why is the program still trying to connect to the older database that does not exist

In your `JDBC` string you have specified database name as `interndata`

```
jdbc:mysql://LocalHost:3306/interndata
```

So, any of the below query either `INSERT` or `SELECT` would be executed under `interndata` database context.

So, when you are executing below query

```
INSERT INTO employee ...
```

It will be executed for `employee` table in `interndata` database. If you want to executed above query in different database context i.e. `internexample`. Then, you need to change `JDBC` sting as

```
jdbc:mysql://LocalHost:3306/internexample
```

Answer (score 1):

> why is the program still trying to connect to the older database that does not exist even thought there is no mention of it in the code?

Nothing you've presented supports the conclusion that that's what is happening.

- In the first place, you are *successfully* connecting to MySQL, else you would get a different exception.
- In the second place, the exception message is entirely consistent with the code you've presented.  Your JDBC URL `jdbc:mysql://LocalHost:3306/interndata?useSSL=false` designates the database as "interndata", you attempt to `INSERT INTO employee`, and the exception message is entirely consistent with this:

  > Table 'interndata.employee' doesn't exist

Instead, the problem seems to be that the expected table is not actually present in the database.  We haven't any basis on which to determine why that might be, so we can only speculate.  Since you mention changing the table name, but you seem also to have selected a different database name, it may be that you changed the table name but left it in the old database.  Alternatively, maybe you performed it on a different database instance -- maybe on a different machine, as that would not move with the program on account of using a `localhost` JDBC URL.  Or maybe the change was not effective at all, or the whole database was since wiped, or etc..

Answer (score -1):

which IDE do you use? eclipse, intellij, netbeans? i run intellij, and if i get these kinds of problems i just press File -> Invalidate caches / restart and 9 out of ten times it works.

reason it does that is because sometimes old references are left behind, and it causes errors. but when you remove all and create them from the actual code you have at the moment, everything you get is "true".